# how to rename nested classes in jaxb xjc

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, xjc

I have a wsdl that imports a schema
I am trying to resolve xjc naming multiple nested MyElementName classes with the same name - which doesn't compile
I have created this binding file below but it gives the error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal class inheritance loop.  
Outer class MyElementName1 may not subclass from inner class: MyElementName1
    at com.sun.codemodel.internal.JDefinedClass._extends(JDefinedClass.java:257)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.ImplStructureStrategy$1._extends(ImplStructureStrategy.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:197)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:151)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:184)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:64)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:87)
```

I I remove the first binding for MyElementName1 it works correctly but only names 1 of the classes, I want to change both names, 
how do I change the binding file so that it will properly name both old nested classes to two unique names I have picked below. I want to do this because I have other mappings with 4 nested classes with the same name so being able to name each class would be needed to tackle the more nested problem areas

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MYWSDL.wsdl">    
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAAA']//xsd:complexType//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']">
            <jaxb:class name="MyElementName1"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>               
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAAA']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='CCC']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']/xsd:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="MyElementName2"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

here is xsd (names of fields changed but rest same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AAA">
<xsd:complexType> 
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="BBB">
     <xsd:complexType> 
          <xsd:element name="MyElementName">        
             <xsd:complexType>              
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CCC">
                  <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="MyElementName">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                          <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element ref="FromDate" />
                            <xsd:element ref="ThruDate" />
                          </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                      </xsd:element>
                      <xsd:element name="DDD">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                          <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element ref="DueDate" />
                          </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                      </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="YYYY" />
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="ZZZZ" />
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:complexType>             
    </xsd:element>               
</xsd:complexType>             
</xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```

the field MyElementName2 is ok, that gets built into the java file if I try binding below, its just the first one that jaxb is mapping to the multiple children - including the one that is mapped with MyElementName2. XPath always maps to one node so maybe its a jaxb option, as it seems to be expanding the input

here is the alternative binding that results in its error below

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MYWSDL.wsdl">    
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAA']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']">
            <jaxb:class name="MyElementName1"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>        
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAA']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:element[@name='Billing']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='CCC']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']/xsd:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="MyElementName2"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

error:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xsd:element[@name='AAA']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']" results in too many target nodes
Failed to parse a schema.
```

Comment: Nobody can check what you're doing unless you provide the XML Schema so that it can be matched with the XPath expressions you are using in the bindings file. --- The XML Schema appears to have deeply nested anonymous types, which is bad. Can you change that - it doesn't mean to change the XML structure!

Comment: I can't provide the xml schema or modify it as its proprietary and given to use to interact with not change. I could likely mock it up with jaxb tags just to get the code but that would be a mess for future changes

Comment: If you don't want to, or can't even refactor (by renaming) the relevant part of the XML Schema then I don't think anybody can help you.

Comment: Seems that in your binding file missing some '/'... but can you add your xsd? in order to help you better.

Comment: for now I switched to xmlbeans, there is not enough reliable information of these types of conditions with jaxb for it to be reliable and fast turn around

Answer (score 5):

JAXB generates one class per one complex type, so I believe you should bind your custom class name to xs:complexType rather than xs:element. Your first XPath refers to the xs:element and I think JAXB does not know how to bind a class to it. Try this binding:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
version="2.1">
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MYWSDL.wsdl">    
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAAA']//xsd:complexType//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']/xs:complexType">
        <jaxb:class name="MyElementName1"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>               
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AAAA']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='CCC']//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']/xsd:complexType">
        <jaxb:class name="MyElementName2"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Personally, I prefer using JAXB to XMLBeans. You should be careful with the latter, because when compiling a deeply nested schema it may generate a structure of nested classes impossible to compile due to filename length limitations (usually 255 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath:

```
//xsd:element[@name='AAA']
//xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='BBB']
//xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']
```

Seems to refer to both of your `MyElementName` elements since they're both under `BBB`. Try to get rid of `//`.

```
//xsd:element[@name='AAA']
/xsd:complexType
/xsd:sequence
/xsd:element[@name='BBB']
/xsd:complexType
/xsd:sequence
/xsd:element[@name='MyElementName']
```

I think this is the right direction you go. You have to customize your anonymous inner complex types.